# Provisionar máquina de Vagrant con Puppet usando el módulo de mysql

Tags: mysql, vagrant, puppet

Estoy tratando de provisionar una máquina de `Vagrant` con `Puppet` usando [éste módulo de mysql](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mysql).

El `Hola mundo` es sencillo, es algo así:

```
class { '::mysql::server':
  root_password           => 'strongpassword',
  remove_default_accounts => true
}
```

Sin embargo, mi objetivo es que luego de hacer `Vagrant up` la primera vez, se construya una máquina de `vagrant` con un servidor de `mysql` listo para ser accedido desde la maquina `host` y aceptar conexiones de un usuario definido.

Mi intento es el siguiente:

```
class { '::mysql::server':
    root_password           => 'strongpass',
    remove_default_accounts => false,
    override_options => {
      mysqld => { bind-address => '0.0.0.0'} //permitir conexiones entrantes desde cualquier ip
    }
  }

//crear una base de datos llamada `mydb`, un usuario y asignarle una contraseña
  mysql::db { 'mydb':
      user     => 'admin',
      password => 'secret',
      host     => '192.168.33.1',
    }

//asignarle todos los permisos al usuario que acabamos de crear
  mysql_grant { 'admin@192.168.33.1/*.*':
    ensure     => 'present',
    options    => ['GRANT'],
    privileges => ['ALL'],
    table      => '*.*',
    user       => 'admin@192.168.33.1',
  }
```

Para probar que todo funcione como es esperado hago mis pruebas así:

- Destruir la máquina de vagrant si ya existiera: `vagrant destroy`
- Crear la máquina de vagrant: `vagrant up`
- Tratar de conectarme desde [MySQLWorkbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

Lo raro es que, al tratar de conectarme, la máquina de `vagrant` no me lo permite pero si hago un reprovisionamiento `vagrant reload --provision` entonces ya puedo conectarme y hacer cualquier `consulta` desde `MySQLWorkbech`. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Te puede servir de ayuda https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash . Mira los scripts que hace servir para mysqll; https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash/blob/master/scripts/mysql.sh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estuve tratando de replicar tu problema y me encontré con un par de problemas, aparte de la instalación del plugin que no es tan fácil (al menos en mac) como dice la documentación.

Lo primero fue esto ([sacado del link del módulo](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mysql)):

> Restart: Whether the service should be restarted when things change. Valid values are 'true', 'false'. Defaults to 'false'.

Entonces en tu `class` de `mysql::server` pon:

```
restart => true,
```

Eso debería ser suficiente pero si quieres tener mayor seguridad del orden en que se ejecutan los bloques agrega esto en la parte de `mysql_grant`:

```
require => Class['::mysql::server']
```

Eso asegurará que esta parte se ejecute hasta que se haya ejecutado la anterior.

Suerte!

Comment: Wow! ya me estaba dando por vencido y me tocaba correr el comando dos veces (que no es tan malo después de todo), pero esto funcionó de maravilla :D

Comment: es este el primero en aparecer?